# Tkinter entry.get() does not update [ Gurobi Python ]

Tags: python, tkinter, gurobi

For simpler demonstration of my problem I'm using a very simple Linear Program.
I want to set the right hand side of one constraint to a certain value that I type into an entry box (Tkinter).
When I click on the button, the variables that are not equal to zero will be shown in the label.

The problem: the initial value of the entry box is 0. When I change it to e.g. 100 I still get the same results. The results don't change whatever I type into the entry box. 
When I hardcode the right hand side value of the constraint to any other value, the results change but not if I change it in my entry box.

It seems like whatever I type into my entry box, Python always takes the initial value, which was 0. It doesn't update to what I've typed in

```
import Tkinter as tk
from gurobipy import *



WIDTH = 330
HEIGHT = 500

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

conslabel = tk.Label(root, text='Constraint value')
conslabel.place(relx=0.1, rely = 0.02)


var = tk.IntVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.02, relwidth=0.3)


button = tk.Button(root, text = "yield result", command = lambda: [setEntryValue(), build_model(entryValue), m.optimize(), results(), m.reset()])
button.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.675, anchor = tk.CENTER)

outputLabel = tk.Label(root, bg='white')
outputLabel.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.85, anchor = tk.CENTER, relheight = 0.2, relwidth = 0.8)

entryValue = 0

def build_model(entryValue):
    m = Model("lp1")
    m.setParam('OutputFlag', False)

    x1 = m.addVar(name="x1")
    x2 = m.addVar(name="x2")

    m.update()

    m.setObjective(5*x1 + 4*x2, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
    m.addConstr(6*x1 + 4*x2 <= 24, "constr_1")
    m.addConstr(1*x1 + 2*x2 <= 6, "constr_2")
    m.addConstr(-1*x1 + 1*x2 <= 1, "constr_3")
    m.addConstr(x2 <= entryValue, "constr_4")

def setEntryValue():
    global entryValue
    entryValue = var.get()
    return entryValue


def labeltext(): 
    finalvars = ''
    for v in m.getVars():
        if v.x != 0:
            finalvars += ' ' + str(v.varName)
    return finalvars

def results():
    for v in m.getVars():
        print('%s: %f' % (v.varName, v.x))  
    print('Obj: %f' % m.objVal)  
    outputLabel['text'] = labeltext()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This does nothing: `m.optimize` and this is static: `x2 <= entryValue`

Comment: oops yes I forgot to delete the m.optimize, but what does x2 <= entryValue being static mean? I only know static in terms of functions... thanks for your help

Comment: ***"what does x2 <= entryValue being static mean? "***: `entryValue` is the inital value and get never chainged

Comment: @BryanOakley ***"show the definition for `addVar`"***: Can we do: `.addVar(name="entry")` and later on `(x2 <= entry.get()`

Comment: Okay, this is getting really weird, I wrote a function setEntryValue() which is just entryValue = int(entry.get()) and a function build_model() which creates the model and I put those two functions in the lambda set of the command of the button, so when I press the button first the entryValue will be set to entry.get() and then the model is created and it still always takes the initial "0" of the entry... I'm gonna update the code

Comment: ***"function `setEntryValue()` which is just `entryValue = int(entry.get())`***: This will not work because of **two** reasons: **1.** `entryValue` is `local` to `def setEntryValue` and useless. **2.** According to [update-the-model-after-editing](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360050245811-How-to-update-the-model-after-editing-the-coefficients-) *Once you call `Model.addConstr()`, it uses the values of `entryValue` to create the constraint, without any reference to `entryValue`*

Comment: okay I changed it to global entryValue to resolve the first issue.. for the second issue: when I click the button first the entryValue will be set to what was typed in according to the function setEntryValue() and then the model is built with the function build_model(entryValue) ... it's build after entryValue is updated I really don't understand why it still takes the initial value ... and thank you very much for your help thus far

Comment: ***"don't understand why it still takes the initial value"***: This is because of using `lambda:`. Using `lambda` will take the inital value, which is `0` and passes it to `build_model(entryValue)`. Remove the parameter, use `def build_model()`

Comment: Relevant [Gurobi python change value of the defined value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22721918/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value of the `Entry` widget about a millisecond after you create it, way before the user has a chance to enter anything. `entryValue` doesn't get updated when the user enters data.

You need to wait to call `entry.get()` until the user has a chance to enter data. Typically that means to do it in a callback associated with a button or menu item.

You should create a function for your "yield result" button instead of using `lambda`. Then, in that function you can set up your data and compute your result.

It should look something like this:

```
def yield_result():

    entryValue = int(entry.get())

    m.setObjective(5*x1 + 4*x2, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
    m.addConstr(6*x1 + 4*x2 <= 24, "constr_1")
    m.addConstr(1*x1 + 2*x2 <= 6, "constr_2")
    m.addConstr(-1*x1 + 1*x2 <= 1, "constr_3")
    m.addConstr(x2 <= entryValue, "constr_4")

    return [m.optimize(), results()]
...    
button = tk.Button(root, text = "yield result", command = yield_result)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is the fact that you need to assign a textvariable to your Entry:

```
entry_var = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvar = entry_var)
```

when you want to get the text in the entry box, you can just use `string = entry_var.get()`

Comment: I tired it with ```var = tk.IntVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)``` and later ```entryValue = var.get()```before but it didn't work, resp. I got exactly the same problem unfortunately

Comment: A `StringVar` is rarely needed with an `Entry` widget, and doesn't solve this particular problem.